# Trying to fetch twitter data through flume

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume

I have been trying to fetch twitter data through flume. The twitter app that i made is named pntgoswami18 and description is BackToCollege. I have done all the key and token replacements required.
But Running the fetch like this:

```
bin/flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume-twitter.conf      -Dflume.root.logger=Debug.console
```

returns a screen with these warnings

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

And the terminal keeps waiting for something. Have kept it running for a while but nothing happened. What am I doing wrong ?

my flume-env.sh file contents are like this

```
$JAVA_OPTS="-Xms500m -Xmx1000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

export FLUME_CLASSPATH='/usr/local/flume/lib'
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue in command is wrong specification of logger.

Replace  `-Dflume.root.logger=Debug.console` by  `-Dflume.root.logger=Debug,console`.

Comment: I tried using your amendments and they are making the script run. But no data is showing up in the HDFS.